# how to combine multiple true/false rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct-values

I have a query with a join on a table containing various true/false columns.
I can enforce DISTINCT & GROUP BY to ensure only single unique row gets returned, however the true/false rows do not behave predictably, example:

```
**Table 1**
loc_id name
-------------
1      a
2      b
3      c
4      d

**Table 2**
prod_id loc_id value
-------------
1       1      abc
2       1      bcd
3       1      def
4       2      fgh

**Table 3**
prod_id flag
-------------
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       1

SELECT DISTINCT name, flag from table1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.prod_id = table2.prod_id
LEFT JOIN table2.loc_id=table1.loc_id
```

This gives me rows containing a list of loc names. However the flag column returns multiple rows sometimes, what i would like to do is combine these rows so that if there is more than one, and they contain both 0 and 1 the query will return only one row with flag set to 1. If multiple rows contain 0, it will return 0 for that row...
I tried using GROUP BY name, which returns unique rows back, however i have noticed that for duplicate rows having both 0 and 1 set in the flag column it will return 0?

Any help appreciated

Comment: So, location can have multiple products, each product has either 1 or 0 set for its flag.prod_table is already massive, had to separate data into another table. Even if it was in the same table same problem applies - i want those multiple rows returning both 0 & 1 to return 1 in the row when I am using GROUP BY name...
Could someone post an example query?

Comment: Do you want it to return 0 when there are more 0s than 1s, and 1 when there are more 1s than 0s?  Or do you want it to return 1 if there is a 1 in the set, and 0 if not?

Comment: as long as there is only one 1 in these multiple rows, it should return a 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you want 1 when there is a 1, and 0 if not, a MAX(flag) should suffice.

```
SELECT name, MAX(flag) from table1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.prod_id = table2.prod_id
LEFT JOIN table2.loc_id=table1.loc_id
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: No problem.  It's often not obvious to use mathematical operations on seemingly boolean variables.  But since TRUE/FALSE are stored as 1/0 in MySQL, it is a handy feature.

Comment: thats what got me confused. I was thinking boolean. :)